# Why can't I bumpfee the 25th tx in an unconfirmed chain?

Tags: bitcoin-core, unconfirmed-transactions, mempool, replace-by-fee

I have a chain of 25 unconfirmed transactions. There's a default mempool limit of 25 chained unconfirmed transactions, so my change output of the 25th transaction is not usable until some of the transactions have confirmed.

To make it confirm, I thought I'd bumpfee the last (25th) tx.

```
$ bitcoin-cli bumpfee <txid> '{"fee_rate": 410}'
error code: -4
error message:
Unable to create transaction. Transaction has too long of a mempool chain
```

Why do I get this error? I'm not making the chain longer, I'm just trying to replace the last tx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the mempool validation logic, the maximum chain size checks are performed without first removing the transaction to be replaced. That is, if there is a chain of 25 unconfirmed transactions such as:

```
txA <-- txB <-- txC <-- ... <-- txY
```

And a candidate for replacing `txY` (`txY'`) is submitted, the mempool limits will be checked with the following topology:

```
txA <-- txB <-- txC <-- ... <-- txY
                            \-- txY'
```

`txA` will therefore fail [the descendants count limit check](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/95a3934cf3973b4083ca30779c8a0ae45fa636ae/src/validation.cpp#L922) (since it's now 26, accounting for itself) [0].

The wallet logic when creating a transaction (not only for fee bumps) mimics this logic ([1](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/95a3934cf3973b4083ca30779c8a0ae45fa636ae/src/wallet/spend.cpp#L1253-L1256), [2](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/95a3934cf3973b4083ca30779c8a0ae45fa636ae/src/node/interfaces.cpp#L700-L708)). This is why the `bumpfee` command for the 25th transaction in an unconfirmed chain fails.

---

[0]: This ignores the RBF carveout for simplicity.

Comment: Ok, thanks. What's the rationale for this behavior? What's the risk of allowing the replacement?

Comment: I wasn't around when it was introduced, but thinking through how one would make this change seems like a lot of hassle for little gain. It could however be documented as it's an interface for external softwares.

Comment: The gain would be that I can get my 25 stuck transactions unstuck. A workaround for this issue is to avoid creating the 25th tx in the first place, to save it fee-bumps so to speak.